# Creating record through Postman (REST API) - request body ignored

Tags: rest-api

I'm experimenting with creating records through Postman. I have authenticated, and I'm able to query data, so I think authentication is OK. However when I'm trying to create or update an Account, it completely ignores the body of the json, and just returns a 200 ok.

I'm new to this, so it might be something very basic I have missed.

[image]

Comment: How did you confirm that Salesforce is ignoring the body?

Comment: What you're seeing in the response body there is the describe data, which is returned by a [GET request to the same endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_basic_info_get.htm). Your setup looks correct; did you actually _send_ a POST request?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, the URL was wrong. It needs to be my.salesforce.com NOT lightning.force.com

Answer (score -1):

In postman check these settings
[image]